# Azure-Runbook: Suppress output of a cmdlet to summary or history

Tags: powershell, azure, automation

In an Azure-runbook, how can one suppress the output of a cmdlet to show up in the summary or history log?

For instance

```
Start-AzureVM -Name ...
```

emits something like

```
PSComputerName        : localhost
PSSourceJobInstanceId : xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
Id                    : azure_adm@foo.com 
Type                  : User
Subscriptions         : xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
Tenants               : xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
PSComputerName        : localhost
PSSourceJobInstanceId : xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
OperationDescription  : Start-AzureVM
```

to the summary.

Comment: try by adding - `| out-null`

Comment: @ramiramilu `| out-null` is not working - throws an exception

Comment: @ramiramilu ex: _Other commands from this module have been packaged as workflow activities, but this command was specifically excluded..._

Comment: Can you show the complete command what you are using?

Comment: @ramiramilu `Start-AzureVM -Name "..." -ServiceName "..." | Out-Null`

Answer (score 0):

You can use "out-null" in Azure-Runbooks only inside "InlineScript {}"

Answer (score 0):

If you assign the output to a variable, then it will not write it to the console.

Try assigning it to `$null` like this:

```
$null = Start-AzureVM -Name ...
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Why does this solve the problem?